# React Hook Form - v7.39.4: How to have correct type for "fields" from useFieldArray in another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'd like to have my `fields` from `useFieldArray` come with the correct type, that should look something like this `FieldArrayWithId<{...}, "users", "id">[]` so I can map those and access properly their `name` and `age` properties.

Problem is, I can't seem to make it work when doing so in another file, the type for `fields` always come as `Record<"id", string>[]`.

So far I've tried:

- Using the generic type in `useForm` on the other file
- Forcing type assertion for `fields` using the correct type
- Even though the doc says it's optional, passing `control` from my `useFormContext` to the `useFieldArray`

Any help is welcome, thank you so much!

Edit: here is a sandbox environment with this issue and comments about it https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-rules-forked-jw970u?file=/src/index.js